# Cutting off overflowing image without overflow: hidden

Tags: css

I have a div with a fixed height, and inside it there is an image. This image is larger than the width and height of the containing div. I want to make the width of the image to match the width of the div, and then make the height of the image automatically generated.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class="portfolio">
        <div class="header">
            Portfolio
        </div>
        <div class="projects">
            <div class="project">
                <img src="../assets/projects/charlotte_folke.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overview">

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

SCSS:

```
.portfolio {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    height: 10%;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #B59762;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.projects {
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.project {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35%;
    overflow: hidden;

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

The problem with this solution, is that the image element still takes up space below the containing div. I want to cut off the image completely, so it only takes up the available space specified by the containing div.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: share the html code as well.

Comment: I added the HTML and all of the SCSS.

Comment: Try styling `img` as `position : absolute` and `height :100%` just add these two properties in your `img`

Comment: @MikeHawkins image should fit-in with which div? is it `projects`?

Comment: .project, without s

Comment: Is this what you looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/27bcg6h4/13/

Comment: also you should provide width to the parent div right? once you set height and width of the parent, Child can follow that route with some changes.